# Appending into a master sheet by row after row by taking first row of each sheets from multiple sheets then move on two second rows appending

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Can someone suggest me on how to appending into a master sheet by row after row by taking the first row of each sheet from multiple sheets then move on to second rows appending, suppose in the first iteration, we have each first row of each sheet, that should copy and paste as row1, row2, row3 into the master sheet, then in the next iteration the second row of each sheet comes and add/append at the end of the master sheet means it would be row4, row5...etc into the master sheet

I even tried below piece of code which sent from the user https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444507/michael
but I can't able to get the right output

```
Public Sub MergeTabs()

'Merges selected tabs (or all visible tabs if only 1 selected) in current workbook into a new tab

Dim i As Integer, wb As Workbook, w As Window, wsTo As Worksheet, wsFrom As Collection   'Worksheet collection
Dim strScope As String, strNewTab As String
Dim raTarget As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set w = ActiveWindow

Set wsFrom = New Collection

If w.SelectedSheets.Count = 1 Then
    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        If wb.Worksheets(i).Visible Then wsFrom.Add wb.Worksheets(i)
    Next
    strScope = "ALL VISIBLE"
Else
    For i = 1 To w.SelectedSheets.Count
        If w.SelectedSheets(i).Visible Then wsFrom.Add w.SelectedSheets(i)
    Next
    strScope = wsFrom.Count & " SELECTED"
End If

strNewTab = InputBox("Merge data from " & strScope & " sheets to new sheet named:", "Merge tabs", "All")
If strNewTab = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Set wsTo = wb.Worksheets.Add(wsFrom(1), Count:=1) 'Add before first selected sheet
wsTo.Name = strNewTab

wsFrom(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
wsTo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

For i = 2 To wsFrom.Count
    wsFrom(i).Range("A2", wsFrom(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells(wsFrom(i).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Cells.Count)).Copy
    wsTo.Cells(wsTo.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

wsTo.Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "Merge Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better if you will show us what you tried... At least try better describe your need. So, do you need to copy only one row? To append each row content in a big one and move this one to the master sheet? Do you need to append the master worksheet rows for each processed worksheets, for corresponding rows? I mean row 1 to append row 1 and so on?

Comment: yes, lets' say in the first iteration each first row of multiple sheets copy into a new master sheet, then move on to each second row of multiple sheets comes and append at the end of master sheet and moves on to 3rd rows of each sheet  comes and append at the end into master sheet and goes on like this

Comment: Appending means to add in the same row... So you need to copy all rows of each sheet, one after the other in the master sheet. But you need all first rows to be one after other and then the second of each and so on? If yes, do all rows have the same number of columns? And do all sheets have the same number of rows?

Comment: let's say in the first iteration we have each first row of each sheet, that copy and paste as row1, row2, row3 into the master sheet, the next iteration second row of each sheet comes and add/append at the end of the master sheet means it would be  row4, row5...etc into the master sheet

Comment: @karupakalas This kind of question was asked (and answered) several times here on Stack Overflow. Please do some research before you ask ([How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)) and try something on your own. If you still get stuck come back with your code/attempt and ask a question related to it. Note that SO is no free code writings service ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)).

Comment: @karupakalas: Started to understand that, but I also asked about number of rows in each sheet if are the same and also if columns of each row are the same. I am asking that in order to see what is to be done for a faster way, meaning to put all rows in an array and drop them in the master sheet at once. This would be the fastest way... I can make preliminary checks to determine all that, but no need to lose time if they would be equal...

Comment: The columns of each sheet are the same, but the rows of each sheet will vary, and also please suggest me how to put them into an array and drop into the master one

Comment: OK. I will prepare a piece of code. But, if you will not try editing your question and paste a piece of code created by you, or collected from internet, until I will come with the code, you will be in danger to have the question closet and I will not be able to post an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please. It firstly counts the maximum number of rows for sheets to be processed, the maximum number of columns and number of sheets. For maximum number of columns, it counts only the sheet first row. So, it must be the longer of the sheet! All that is done for being able to correctly dimension the `arrFin` array which will collect all the lines. It will have more rows then necessary, multiplying the max number of rows with the sheets number. Then the array is filled with data. I switched the rows with columns because only the second dimension of the array can be `Redim`, preserving the existing data. Finally the transposed array is dropped in the Master sheet at once. It should work very fast... Please, confirm that it works as you need.

```
Private Sub testApendCopySameRows()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wDest As Worksheet, arrWork As Variant, arrFin As Variant
  Dim lastCol As Long, lastC As Long, lastColM As Long, lastR As Long, nrSheets As Long
  Dim maxR As Long, maxRows As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  Set wDest = Worksheets("Master1") ' please, use here your master sheet name
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> wDest.Name Then
      'If ws.Name = "sh1" Or ws.Name = "sh2" Then 'used (by me) for testing
        nrSheets = nrSheets + 1
        lastC = ws.Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lastC > lastCol Then lastCol = lastC
        maxR = ws.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If maxR > maxRows Then maxRows = maxR
      'End If
    End If
  Next

  ReDim arrFin(1 To lastCol, 1 To maxRows * nrSheets)
  ReDim arrWork(1 To 1, 1 To lastCol)
  k = 1 'arrFin first row
  For i = 1 To maxRows
    For Each ws In Worksheets
      If ws.Name <> wDest.Name Then
        'If ws.Name = "sh1" Or ws.Name = "sh2" Then
          lastR = ws.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
          If i <= lastR Then
             'input the same rows content in the array:
             arrWork = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, lastCol)).value
             For j = 1 To lastCol
                arrFin(j, k) = arrWork(1, j)
             Next j
             k = k + 1
             Erase arrWork
             ReDim arrWork(1 To 1, 1 To lastCol)
          End If
        'End If
      End If
    Next
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To lastCol, 1 To k - 1)
  wDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin, 2), UBound(arrFin, 1)).value = _
                                        WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```

Do not forget to use your Master sheet name in `Set wDest = Worksheets("Master1")`!

Comment: yes, I used Master1 as my master sheet name, but I m getting type mismatch error here
in the for loop

For j = 1 To lastCol
                arrFin(j, k) = arrWork(1, j)
             Next j

Comment: @karupakalas: Check the next, please, being on the error:  What value does `arrWork(1, j)` show when you move the cursor over it? If it is nothing, check what `ws.Name` shows on which row. For that see what value `i` and `j` have. Then go to that sheet (in Excel), on the `i` row and `l` column. What do you see there in that cell? Is it possible that your columns to not be in the same number for all sheets??

Comment: its showing arrWork(1, j) = <Type mismatch>

Comment: What value `k` shows, and also `j`? Check also what `lastCol`shows. Do you have TeamViewer installed?

Comment: its showing as j =1, and k =1, and lastCol = 1

Comment: How `lastCol` can be 1? Do you have only one column in your sheets? Please check if your last sheet is not strange and it must be escaped like we proceeded with `ws.Name <> wDest.Name`... What about TeamViewer? I will leave my office in about half an hour. Can I connect to your computer?

Comment: @karupakalas: Still alive? :)

Comment: I have 9 columns in each sheet,, and no columns are empty/blank/gaps, but its reading number of sheets correctly, and reading column name correctly, but at the place of  arrFin(j, k) = arrWork(1, j) its throwing type mismatch error

Comment: Because it counted 1 column in one of your sheets! probably, the last one. Try another sub with one code line: `Debug.Print Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. What does it show in Immediate Window? Press Ctrl + G when being in  VBE.

Comment: Should I deduce that you do not use TeamViewer?

Comment: I don't need. I supposed you would need that... I only wanted to help. But I will leave my office in some minutes. If you send now your ID and password I will connect. In such a case please have your workbook open and a blanc notepad window to communicate.